# Linked list implementation using optionals

Tags: ios, swift

Given the following definition of a linked list node:

```
class ListNode {
    var value: Int = 0
    var node:  ListNode? = nil
    static var root:ListNode? = nil

    init() {
    }
    init(value:Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
```

Then the following implementation of an insert function will work:

```
    if (ListNode.root == nil) {
        ListNode.root = ListNode(value: value)
    }
    else {
        var temp = ListNode.root
        while (temp!.node != nil) {
            temp = temp!.node
        }
        temp!.node = ListNode(value: value)
    }
```

However this implementation of the same function does not work:

```
var temp = ListNode.root
while temp != nil {
    temp = temp!.node
}
temp = ListNode(value: value)
```

Why does the latter not work and how could it be re-written (in a succinct form and without using recursion) to work?
If the problem is due to the fact that temp is a copy and not a reference then how can it be turned into a reference?

(It doesn't work because ListNode.root remains unaltered after the insertion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListNode.root remains unaltered in latter case because it is not being assigned anything anywhere.

And I would implement this as follows:

```
class ListNode {

    static var root: ListNode? = nil
    static var tail: ListNode? = nil

    var nextNode: ListNode? = nil

    var value: Int = 0

    init() { }

    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }

    static func insert(value: Int) {
        switch tail {

        case nil:
            ListNode.root = ListNode(value: value)
            ListNode.tail = ListNode.root

        default:
            let newTail = ListNode(value: value)
            ListNode.tail?.nextNode = newTail
            ListNode.tail = newTail

        }
    }

}
```

**[UPD]**

In swift there are two types of properties/variables, that is, value and object.

When the value property (e.g. `Int` or some `struct`) is being assigned to a (temporary) variable it is being copied.  And the new variable would be a different thing from the original, that is, any change to either would not automatically reflect in the other.

Now, the objects are a bit different.  They are essentially pointers copied by value.  I.e. if you have two variables that *refer* *to* *the* *same* *object*, then changing *property* of one of them would be "seen" by the other (because pointers of both point to the same area of memory).  But if both are nils, then there is nothing to share.

Also if you assign `varA` with new object, then that will keep `varB` pointing to the same old object.  I.e. the following:

```
let varA = SomeObject()
let varB = varA
lat varA = SomeObject()
```

... will end up with `varA` and `varB` holding references to different objects.

Comment: A new node is being assigned to temp, and temp has previously been set to ListNode.root. Hence if the new node is not being assigned then presumably it is because temp is a copy and not a reference to the the root. So how is the code re-written to make temp a reference to root rather than a copy of root?

Comment: When you operate with class instances (i.e. objects) you operate with references implicitly.  So if you assign temp with ListNode.root value, and list is empty yet, then temp is going to be nil.  Next thing is you try to traverse from nil, which will bail out immediately.  Then you assign temp with new object instance, but you forget to assign same thing to the class' static property.

Comment: But if temp is a reference to the static root then why does the root need to be assigned to directly, why can't be it assigned to indirectly via temp as it would be if this code was C or C++ or similar?

Comment: Ok, now I see where the confusion comes from.  `temp` is not a reference to the static root.  In other words, it is not a reference to the reference held by static root.  It is just a reference to some ListNode object.  If the list is not empty then `let temp = ListNode.root` would assign `temp` with a reference to the exactly same object that root points to, and any change to `temp`'s object properties would be reflected in the root (because it's just the same object).  But if list is empty then `temp` gets nil, and it's a "different" `nil` from the one that root holds.

Comment: Thanks, but why is it inconsistent? In order words why is it the same if its not nil, but its different if it is nil?

Answer (score 0):

In your second case, you are assigning the new node to `temp` but then you aren't assigning temp back into your `ListNode` structure.

This line

```
 var temp = ListNode.root
```

says, make a new variable `temp` which is a reference to a `ListNode` and put in it the same reference that is held in `ListNode.root`.  Since `ListNode.root` is initially `nil` it means that `temp` will also hold nil.  `temp` is just some space on the stack, so when you assign a new object reference to it, it doesn't update `ListNode.root`.  You would need to take a reference to `ListNode.root` using & for that to work, but using pointers in this way is more "C" than "Swift" and just not what you would do.  In Swift `&` is only used for `inOut` parameters to a function.

In Swift you can't do much better than you already have (unless you introduce a tail reference as was suggested in the other answer).

Arguably it is better to have "readable" code than "clever" code anyway.

Also, the use of a static class `root` limits the utility of your class because you can only ever have one list

I would use two classes.  One for your list and then your existing `ListNode` inside the `List` -

```
Class List {
    var root: ListNode? = nil

    func insert(value:Int) {
        var newNode=ListNode(value: value)
        if (self.root == nil) {
            self.root=newNode
        }
        else {
            var destinationNode=self.root!
            while (destinationNode.node != nil) {
                destinationNode=destinationNode.node!;
            }
            destinationNode.node=newNode
        }
    }
}

class ListNode {
    var value: Int = 0
    var node:  ListNode? = nil

    init(value:Int) {
        self.value = value
    }   
}
```